# Flask + Celery - Maximum Recursion Depth Error

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to use Celery to turn my Flask app into an asynchronous one. The app is designed to accept a request, determine which function to route the request to, and then pass the request and some extra parameters to the corresponding function. The app works fine when Celery is removed, but when trying to use the library I am consistently getting the following error:

```
[2017-04-27 00:26:40,218: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Johns-MacBook-Pro.local ready.
[2017-04-27 00:26:40,469: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: DecodeError(RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object',),) [type:'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:'binary' headers:{}]
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Below is an extract from my code:

```
import json

from flask import Flask, request, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config.default')
api = Api(app)

import app_program
import util

# Celery settings
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


# The class for executing adjust
class Events(Resource):
    n = app_program.AppProgram()

    def get(self):
        # Retrieve the specified parameters
        params = request.args.to_dict()
        params['request'] = request
        if 'd' in params.keys(): # Handles
            params.update(json.loads(params['d']))
            del params['d']
            # Determine if the visitor id exists
        visitor_id, visitor_id_exists = self.n.visitor_id(**params)
        params['visitor_id'] = visitor_id
        # Save the pageview
        if util.base_text(params['type'].lower()) == 'pageview':
            self.save_pview.delay(**params)
        else:
            self.save_event.delay(**params)

        return {"result": "success"}

    @celery.task
    def save_pview(self, params):
        """
        Saves the pageview
        :param params: the input parameters
        :return:
        """
        self.n.save_pview(**params)

    @celery.task
    def save_event(self, params):
        """
        Saves the visitor event
        :param params: the input parameters
        :return:
        """
        self.n.save_event(**params)

api.add_resource(Events, '/event')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

The error message doesn't seem to provide any useful information:

```
[2017-04-27 00:39:31,584: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: DecodeError(RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object',),) [type:'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:'binary' headers:{}]

body: b'\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x07\x00\x00\x00tasksetq\x01NX\t\x00\x00\x00timelimitq\x02NN\x86q\x03X\t\x00\x00\x00callbacksq\x04NX\x05\x00\x00\x00chordq\x05NX\x03\x00\x00\x00etaq\x06NX\x03\x00\x00\x00utcq\x07\x88X\x07\x00\x00\x00expiresq\x08NX\x04\x00\x00\x00taskq\tX\x0e\x00\x00\x00app.save_pviewq\nX\x08\x00\x00\x00errbacksq\x0bNX\x07\x00\x00\x00retriesq\x0cK\x00X\x04\x00\x00\x00argsq\r]q\x0eX\x02\x00\x00\x00idq\x0fX$\x00\x00\x0019430fd1-fc1d-41b5-9380-9bd4f5b9cc07q\x10X\x06\x00\x00\x00kwargsq\x11}q\x12(X\x07\x00\x00\x00fullurlq\x13X:\x00\x00\x00https://www.example.com#.q\x14X\n\x00\x00\x00visitor_idq\x15X$\x00\x00\x0021cb1d079cfffsdf8507ce18582cq\x16X\x0b\x00\x00\x00fingerprintq\x17X\x08\x00\x00\x0075201686q\x18X\x04\x00\x00\x00typeq\x19X\x08\x00\x00\x00pageviewq\x1aX\x08\x00\x00\x00timezoneq\x1bX\x03\x00\x00\x00ESTq\x1cX\t\x00\x00\x00visitoridq\x1dh\x16X\x07\x00\x00\x00requestq\x1ecwerkzeug.local\nLocalProxy\nq\x1f)\x81q... (677b)
```

Also, is there anyway I can make it print the full body?

Comment: There should be traceback on the celery worker telling you where the recursion happens.

Comment: The body of the error cuts off before anything useful: see update above

Comment: Try running celery with `-f LOGFILE`.

Comment: Same issue, it still cuts off the error message and does not print the full body.